# Est-ce qu’il y a des mots familiers qui vont mal ensemble ?

Tags: argot, langage-des-jeunes

Je peux comprendre qu’on ne peut pas utiliser du langage soutenu en combinaison avec des mots qui sont censés être familiers, comme ceux qui sont issus de l’argot. Y a-t-il d'autres règles qui doivent être suivies lorsqu’on utilise le langage familier, y a-t-il des « sous-vocabulaires » qui ne doivent pas être mêlés ? Je croirais qu’un mot verlan comme « tebé » est seulement dit par la jeunesse, alors qu’il y a aussi beaucoup de mots argotiques qui sont plutôt utilisés par des gens plus vieux, comme « pognon ».

Comment: *Rouspéter* ce n'est pas du verlan.

Comment: Je suis désolé. Je pensais que ce mot venait de « protester ». J’espère que « tebé » et un meilleur exemple de verlan.

Comment: Ouais ça c'est du verlan. Je l'aurais écrit *teubé*, mais je ne crois pas qu'il existe encore d'instance de normalisation :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[L'argot 'classique'](http://www.priceminister.com/offer/buy/372224/Boudard-Etienne-La-Methode-A-Mimile-Livre.html?ModPagespeed=noscript)* du XXe siècle, ou *[ce genre de dictionnaire](http://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/?index=verlan&let=a)* vous donneront des exemples et des formules cohérents.

Le véritable argot, s'il est souvent plein de sous-entendus très crus n'est jamais vulgaire, il réussit à trouver une expression poétique qui chante vertement l'amour, parle du sordide sans complaisance, se moque sans méchanceté des travers d'autrui.

Il y a quelque chose des troubadours et trouvères de l'ancien temps pour célébrer la fierté des braves gens (des non bourgeois, des sans pouvoirs, des sans [trop d']argent).

Le *[louchébem](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louch%C3%A9bem)*, le verlan, et ensuite les différentes expressions contemporaines donnent des tonalités différentes et sont soumises aux modes de leurs temps.

Mélanger de l'argot 'ancien' avec les dernières expressions à la mode n'est pas toujours compris par ceux qui n'étaient pas nés à l'époque où celui-là était en cours.

[*Pognon*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pognon) c'est de  l'argot d'avant-guerre, *teubé* est un petit jeunot de la fin du deuxième millénaire ; ne pas parler de *teubé* à un ancien qui n'est pas en contact avec la jeunesse mais utiliser par exemple *[faire la bamboula](http://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/definition-glossaire-f-bamboula.html)* (mot vieilli de l'argot militaire 1913).